# Angular 8 Scroll to top not working with agm-map

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-routing, agm-map

When I change route and go to a page where there's the `agm-map` I can't scroll the window to top.
I've tried using

```
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
```

and then in `onActivate`:

```
  onActivate(event) {
    window.scroll(0, 0);
  }
```

I've also tried

```
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
```

and

```
this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
  if (!(evt instanceof NavigationEnd)) {
    return;
  }
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

inside ngOnInit but it doesn't work: I always land on the map when navigating to the page, and not at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Remove any height style applied to body